# Каким образом можно реализовать автоапдейт запрещенных слов

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

пишу бота-модератора, нужно сделать фильтр плохих слов. Начал писать, **удивился**, устал, подумал, что зачем вручную писать 10% слов русского языка, если по-любому можно можно скачать какой-нибудь готовенький архив. А потом предположил, что может же быть функция автообновления этого же архива с того же самого сайта.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не стоит удивляться, однако вопрос то какой хотели задать?

Comment: Хотел спросить, как реализовать?